# knockout js button click select all the checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am using Knockout js for binding, i am binding list of data with checkbox,the data i am fetching and binding to list item including checkbox to all item,now i need to create new button name "select-all" and when i click that button i need to select all the checkbox and i need to get all data from selected checkbox how to achieve this need help..

```
<div>
<input type="button" value="Select-All" data-bind="click:SelectAll" />
</div>
<div  id="List" data-bind="foreach:items">
<ul>
<li>
<span data-bind="text:userId" style="display:none"></span>
<span style="margin-top: 10px;font-size: 22px;font-weight: bold;padding-left:0px;" data-bind="text:username"></span>
<input  type="checkbox" data-bind="value:userId(),click:$root.toggle" />                   
</li>
</ul>
</div>

 //ViewModel
function userViewModel()
 var self=this;
     {
    function userList(userId, userName)
     {
      var self=this;
     self.userID=ko.observable(userId);
     self.userName=ko.observable(userName);
     self.Selected = ko.observable(false);
     }
   self.toggleAssociation = function (item) {
     //here i am getting the individual selected checkbox Item 
   }

 //This part is not working 
  self.SelectAll = function() {
  console.log("in")
 self.items().forEach(function(item) {
    item.Selected(true);
});
  };

   self.items = ko.observableArray();
     self.add = function (userId, userName,){
     self.items.push(new FriendsContact(userId, userName)
   }
};

 //Page Load  
 $(function () {
var viewModel = new userViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

 //Get the data from database//
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',      
    url: baseUrl + 'xxx/xxx/xxxxx',
    success: function (data) { 
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                viewModel.add(value.userId, value.userName)
            });
    }
})
});
```

Comment: Are you sure, your code is working besides the mentioned issue? I tried to create a fiddle and have found numerous issues

Comment: @yes its working fine with all other function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot define a variable before your function scope begins where you put `{`  . Below deceleration is WRONG

```
function userViewModel()
  var self=this;
     {
```

Based on What I see from your code I'll show you how to approach such a thing.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/103/

**HTML:**

```
 <div>
      <input type="button" value="Select-All" data-bind="click:SelectAll,visible:ShowSelectAllBtn" />
      <input type="button" value="UnSelect-All" data-bind="click:UnSelectAll,visible:ShowSelectAllBtn() == 0" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" value="Add" data-bind="click:add" />
    </div>
    <div  id="List" data-bind="foreach:items">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <span data-bind="text:userId"></span>
          <span style="margin-top: 10px;font-size: 22px;font-weight: bold;padding-left:0px;" data-bind="text:userName"></span>
          <input  type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:Selected" />                   
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

**JS:**

```
var data = [{userId:1 , userName : "UserName1"},{userId:2 , userName : "UserName2"}];

function userViewModel(){
   var self = this;
   self.items = ko.observableArray();
   self.ShowSelectAllBtn = ko.observable(true);
   self.loadData = function (){
     // here you have your ajax 
     //maping fake data assuming it is inside the ajax's success
     self.items($.map(data, function (item) {
       return new userItemViewModel(item);
     }));
   }
  self.SelectAll = function() {
    self.ShowSelectAllBtn(false);
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.items(), function (item) {
      item.Selected(true);
    });
  };
  self.UnSelectAll = function() {
    self.ShowSelectAllBtn(true);
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.items(), function (item) {
      item.Selected(false);
    });
  };
  var i = 2;
  self.add = function (userId, userName){
    // creating a fake json object with a userId and a userName
    userId = i++;
    userName = "userName" + i;
    obj = {userId:userId , userName : userName} ;
    self.items.push(new userItemViewModel(obj) );
  }
};

var userItemViewModel = function (data){
    var self = this;
    self.userId = ko.observable(data.userId);
    self.userName = ko.observable(data.userName);
    self.Selected = ko.observable(false);
    self.Selected.subscribe(function(newValue){
     //individual selected checkbox 
       console.log(newValue);
       console.log(self.userId());
       console.log(self.userName());
    }, self);
}

var viewModel = new userViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
// Load data
viewModel.loadData();
```

Comment: @thanks for your time,it was really helpful,but i cant select individuals checkbox "<input  type="checkbox" data-bind="value:userId(),click:$root.toggle" />" this toggle from which i was getting particular user ID,now its not working

Comment: ,i am getting the individual value when i click checkbox,now i want to call new function which should  get  individual checkbox the data

Comment: i have added click event to check box, to get individual value related to that checkbox,i am get individual  value when i click checkbox,but checkbox is not selected need help

Comment: thanks Matt for your time,but i solved in different way according to my requirements

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new method to your `userViewModel`:

```
self.SelectAll = function() {
    self.items().forEach(function(item) {
        item.Selected(true);
    });
};
```

Comment: @thanks for your time,its not working, its not hitting the function,when i click on the selectAll button,bcoz its outside the foreach item

Comment: @Nikil, Since "its outside the foreach item", your scope would already be `$root` and if you did declare `SelectAll` on `self`, you should be fine. Provide more code otherwise.

Comment: @Nikil, Are you missing the declaration of `self` (something like `var self = this`)? Check your console for errors first.

Comment: ,nope, already i have declared it, i have missed the declaration part while posting this question

Answer (score 0):

@[haim770](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1625737/haim770) is right that you will have to loop over elements and set `item.Selected(true)`. Now issue is :

```
<input  type="checkbox" data-bind="value:userId(),click:$root.toggle" />
```

- First, checkbox is mapped to `userId` and not `Selected`.
- Second, checkbox does not have value binding. It has `checked` binding. So it should be:

`<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:$data.Selected,click:$root.toggle" />`

Also you should avoid using `$root`. You can replace it with `$parent.toggle`

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/7fbo0u54/)

Comment: @thanks,but i dont know why select button could not hit the function self.SelectAll

Comment: i tried it,but when i add the selectAll button inside the foreach "foreach:items" loop its working,if i add it before foreach loop its not working

Comment: @Nikil there must be an issue with scope. Try logging a temporary variable in a span.